# OpenSceneGraph Texture2D image "dirty" vs "setImage" performance

Tags: c++, windows, performance, openscenegraph

I have a 2D texture placed over rectangular area - it's a dynamic texture image (640x480).

```
tex = new osg::Texture2D;
tex->setDataVariance( osg::Object::DYNAMIC );
tex->setResizeNonPowerOfTwoHint( false );
tex->setFilter( osg::Texture2D::MIN_FILTER, osg::Texture2D::NEAREST );
tex->setFilter( osg::Texture2D::MAG_FILTER, osg::Texture2D::NEAREST );
tex->setImage(myImage);
```

My image data is updated in other thread often (each N milliseconds):

```
myImage->setImage(
    width,
    height,
    1,
    3,
    GL_BGR,
    gl_data_size,
    (BYTE *)newImageData,
    osg::Image::AllocationMode::USE_MALLOC_FREE
);
```

And after that I want to update rendered image, if I use dirty( thought this was a best way for update ) on image set to texture, e.g.

```
// Update callback
...
myImage->dirty();
...
```

My performance is about 7-8 times slower than if I use just image replacement with same pointer.

```
// Update callback
...
tex->setImage(myImage);
...
```

Reading documentation and gidelines of OSG makes me think the correct way is - 'dirty()'. But it's extremly slow. Do I missunderstand something or there is a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using not the latest (3.0.1) version of OSG, since it lacks the "dirty" method for Image class.
In previous versions (2.x):

```
inline void Image::dirty()
{
    ++_modifiedCount;
    if (_bufferObject.valid())
        _bufferObject->dirty();
}
```

**dirty()** in turns resets all compiled lists for **_bufferObject**.
On the other hand **setImage** begins like this:

```
void Texture2D::setImage(Image* image)
{
    if (_image == image) return;
    ...
}
```

so in your case it does nothing, if you are using the same pointer for the image.
That's why it's faster, but I don't know how OSG updates the actual texture if nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is calling dirty() on your image.

Try adding a osg::PixelBufferObject to your image to speed up the transfer to the graphics card.

```
myImage->setPixelBufferObject(new osg::PixelBufferObject(myImage));
```